# ORA-02158: invalid CREATE INDEX option - when executing Collection in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

My goal in the following proc is to accomplish the following:

1. Get index syntax of specific table
2. Drop and create table with new data
3. Create index for new table

I've been able to store index syntax in Collection variable `IX_L` with the help of `BULK COLLECT INTO`.

But I'm struggling with executing the `CREATE INDEX` that's stored there.
When I loop through `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE IX_L(i);`  I get an error `ORA-02158: invalid CREATE INDEX option`.
But, when I execute the same exact text explicitly and not from withing the Collection variable it works fine, so it doesn't seem like there is a problem with my `CREATE INDEX` syntax.

I would appreciate any help.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MyProc 

AS



  V_SQL      CLOB;

  TYPE INDEX_TBL IS TABLE OF CLOB;

  IX_L   INDEX_TBL;

 
BEGIN

  V_SQL := '

    select

    ''CREATE '' || IX.UNIQUENESS ||'' INDEX '' || IX.OWNER || ''.'' || IX.INDEX_NAME

    || '' ON DWH.TBL ('' || IX_COLS.COLS || '');''

    from All_Indexes IX

    JOIN

         (SELECT TABLE_NAME,INDEX_NAME,listagg (COLUMN_NAME,'','') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) AS COLS

          FROM DBA_IND_COLUMNS T

          where 1=1

          AND t.TABLE_OWNER = ''DWH''

          AND t.TABLE_NAME = ''TBL''

          GROUP BY TABLE_NAME,INDEX_NAME)  IX_COLS

          ON IX.INDEX_NAME = IX_COLS.INDEX_NAME AND IX.TABLE_NAME = IX_COLS.TABLE_NAME

    where 1=1

    AND IX.OWNER = ''DWH''

    AND IX.TABLE_NAME = ''TBL''

    ';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL BULK COLLECT INTO IX_L;

END;


 

BEGIN

   FOR i IN 1 .. IX_L.COUNT

   LOOP

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(IX_L(i));

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE IX_L(i);

   END LOOP;

   COMMIT;

END;

 

 

/*

BEGIN

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX DWH.I3032K_PK ON DWH.SH3032K_BANK_ACNT_DOCUMENTS (OBJECT_ID,SOURCE_ETL)';

END;

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

Needed to delete the `;` at the `SELECT`, right before the  `from All_Indexes`.

This would be correct:

```
select

''CREATE '' || IX.UNIQUENESS ||'' INDEX '' || IX.OWNER || ''.'' || IX.INDEX_NAME

|| '' ON DWH.TBL ('' || IX_COLS.COLS || '')''

from All_Indexes IX`
```